# Google Script Charts Accessing attributes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Firstly – I have only been using java Script and Google Apps Script for about a week.
I am trying to automate the marking of quite a number of googlesheets completed by students.
My plan is to have a master google sheet  with the criteria to be marked and the marks to be awarded as follows.
This is sheet 2 from master sheet

```
Question    Criteria    Cell reference    Correct answer            Marks 
Question 1  FontWeight      A1              bold                      1
Question 2  FontFamily      A1          Times New Roman               2
Question 3  FontSize        A1              16                        2
Question 4  Value           A1  Tables and Graphs by Fred Nerk        1
Question 5  Heading Sheet   Heading Tables and Graphs by Fred Nerk    1
Question 6  ChartTitle      Chart Title Commonwealth Medal Tally 2014 2
Question 7  ChartType       Chart Type        AREA                    1
Question 8  Value           A3                Rank                    1
Question 9  Value           B3               Country                  1
Question 10 Number          A4                  1                     1
etc
```

My code for the lookup is as follows:
I send these  variables to the module:
Mysht is master sheet 2
Studsheet is student spreadsheet
Studsht1 is students answer sheet
Criteria  as per table above
Reference from table above
correctAns from table above
I have been able to do some chart work
I then process student answer against correct answer and give mark in a report etc

```
    function LookupCriteria(mysht2,Studsht1,reference,Criteria,correctAns,Studsheet){
    switch(Criteria) {
case "FontSize":
    testvalue = Studsht1.getRange(reference).getFontSize()
    break;
case "FontFamily":
   testvalue = Studsht1.getRange(reference).getFontFamily();
    break;
 case "FontWeight":
    testvalue = Studsht1.getRange(reference).getFontWeight();
  break;
case "Value":
    testvalue = Studsht1.getRange(reference).getValue();
  var lenanswer=correctAns.length;
  testvalue=testvalue.substring(0,lenanswer);
    break;
case "Heading":
    testvalue = StudSheet.getName();
  var lenanswer=correctAns.length;
  testvalue=testvalue.substring(0,lenanswer);
    break;
case "ChartTitle":
  var StudChart=Studsht1.getCharts()[0];
  var option = "title"
  testvalue=StudChart.getOptions().get(option);
     break;
case "ChartType":
  var StudChart=Studsht1.getCharts()[0];
  testvalue=Charts.ChartType;
     break;
case "Number":
  testvalue=Studsht1.getRange(reference).getValue();
  return testvalue;
// testvalue is the student answer
}
```

My Problem  is:
I cannot find documentation or code to access information from Charts 
Example How do I “Get” the colours for the columns.“ or the font used in the horizontal Axis?
All documentation is about building charts.
Cheers Col Taylor
PS I know this code is not best practice. Best to use arrays and load all data etc
I really just need to know if this request is possible?
Thanks
Cheers Col Taylor

Comment: What is the "Charts Example" that you are referring to?  Is it in the Apps Script help reference?  Do you have a link?

Comment: Thanks so much for answering.  Sorry full stop missing after Charts. I would like to access the information about a chart. For example what is the colour of a column. What is the font used on the horizontal axis. I do not wish to change these. I want to compare them against what the student should have put and award an appropriate mark as per table. Cheers Col

Answer (score 0):

The array of Chart objects returned from `getCharts` is of type `EmbeddedChart`, for which the [documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart).

Have a look at `ChartOptions` which can be retrieved from each chart using [`getOptions()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getoptions), and [`modify()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#modify) which can be used to make changes - these contain some code snippets that illustrate making changes to the options of a Chart.

You will see that there are a whole range of different chartBuilder types, which you'll need to use one of when making changes to your chart, and each has different options that can be set - it's quite an extensive set of objects and methods but the documentation that is linked onwards from `EmbeddedChart` should have you covered.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have read this documentation but it addresses Modifying or Building charts. There does not appear to be much reference to assigning a variable to a chart attribute -  except "title" and "type" of Chart as per code above.  Cheers Col